# Global variable became null when jumping to a function during the porting process

Tags: c, gcc, migration

I am trying to port a program running on Linux to Windows. This program is a multi-threaded program, and due to the initial design not being perfect enough, many global variables are scattered throughout the code. Now I have encountered a very tricky problem: when jumping to a certain function, an unused global variable is set to 0x0.

The compiler version I'm using on Linux is `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)`, while the compiler version I'm using on Windows 10 is `gcc.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 12.2.0`.

By examining the memory contents, I found that the address of this global variable is very close to the address of the function being jumped to (as shown in the figure below):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aypCR.png)
By using the objdump command to check the segment of the executable file, the layout of the memory is as follows(a part of):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w0J7.png)
I want to know the reason for this problem and hope to find a solution.

-----ADDITION------

Sorry, my description is not very clear, and here's a simplified example:

```
// file1.h
extern struct ITEM *item;
void init();
```

```
// file1.c
struct ITEM *item;
void init() {
    item = (struct ITEM *) malloc(sizeof(struct ITEM));
    item->a = 1;
    item->b = 2;
    ...
}
```

```
// file2.h
void funcA() {
    // never use item
  ...
}
```

```
// main.c
...
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
...

void main(void) {
    init();
    funcA();
}
```

After I call the `init()` function, the global variable `item` is initialized and assigned a value, but when calling the `funcA()` function, after the `call` instruction in assembly is executed, the `item` pointer becomes `0x0`

Comment: Global variables are automatically initialized to 0. If it's unused, it will always have that value.

Comment: When you say "*jumping* to a function", do you mean *calling* the function? Is it possible to create a [mre] to show us?

Comment: Why is the variable being set to `0x0` a "very tricky problem"? What did you expect it to be set to?

Comment: Oh, and [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)! Copy-paste text *as text*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure! I apologize, this is my first time asking a question in this community, and I have re-edited and added supplementary explanations after learning more about it. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: How do you check the value of `item`? In a debugger? What happens if you step over the function call, does `item` stay with the wrong value? And why do you have a global variable to begin with? What problem is it supposed to solve? Why can't you have local variable that you pass as an argument to the functions that need it? Or for the `init` function return the pointer?

Comment: This is a simplified example, the original codebase is huge and there are more global variables than this one. Below are my answers to your questions: 0. I debugged it using the gdb debugger. 1. If I skip this function, the pointer to the `item`  will not be set to `0x0`. However, some data will not be updated later because this function is not executed, leading to the failure to continue executing. Interestingly, this function is called in a loop, and I found that in the latest debug, the function works fine when it is first called, but problems arise when it is called the second time.

Comment: 2. This global variable is frequently accessed in the file where it is located (and has a value only in the initialization function), but I did not figure out where to put it in the data structure when i wrote it, so I use it as a global variable. After the pointer to this global variable becomes `0x0`, the next function will use this pointer, which will cause a segmentation fault, and this happens when the value was needed.

Comment: 3. The theoretically reasonable solution is to write this variable into some structure and pass it as a function argument. Unfortunately, there are 20+ functions in this file, and almost all of them will use this global variable and are called by many other functions, so it would be quite a painful task to modify them. But if I have to do it, I will rewrite the code instead of adding "sxxt" on top of the "sxxt code."(HAHA just kidding)

Comment: Well if the variable have its expected value before the call, but not after, then it could be argued that it's a problem in the function itself. Have you stepped through the function line by line to see exactly when and where the value changes? Perhaps you go out of bounds for some other global variable which just happens to lie next in memory?

Comment: At the beginning, I also thought this was the case, but when I debugged instruction by instruction using gdb, I found that the global variable was modified when the `call` instruction was executed. But it is well known that the `call` instruction will not modify the contents of the data segment, and its jump address is only close to the address of the global variable pointer rather than the same

Comment: Without a proper [mre] that actually replicates the problem, there's really nothing we can do to help you.

Answer (score 2):

> when jumping to a certain function, an unused global variable is set to 0x0.

"Global variables" - variables with *file scope*, are always initialized to zero unless explicitly initialized to something else by the programmer,  since they have *static storage duration*. Your program behaves as expected - so what's wrong appears to be your expectations, not the program behavior.

Sources: C17 5.1.2 and 6.7.9 §10.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm sorry if my vague description may have misled your understanding. Now I have re-edited and added a simple example illustration, and I hope you can provide further clarification.